# How do I send mail from a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, email

I want to send email from a Ruby application. Is there a call in the core language to do this or is there a library I should use? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use [ActionMailer](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ActionMailer) you can use [Net::SMTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/index.html) (for the actual sending) together with [tmail](https://github.com/mikel/tmail) for easily creating emails (with multiple parts, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'net/smtp'
SMTP_SERVER = 'mailserver01' #change to your server

def send_emails(sender_address, recipients, subject, message_body)
    recipients.each do |recipient_address|
        message_header =''
        message_header << "From: <#{sender_address}>\r\n"
        message_header << "To: <#{recipient_address}>\r\n"
        message_header << "Subject: #{subject}\r\n"
        message_header << "Date: " + Time.now.to_s + "\r\n"
        message = message_header + "\r\n" + message_body + "\r\n"
        Net::SMTP.start(SMTP_SERVER, 25) do |smtp|
            smtp.send_message message, sender_address, recipient_address
        end
    end
end
send_emails('sender@domain.com',['recip1@test.com', 'recip2@other.com'],'test Email',"Hi there this is a test email hope you like it")
```

Comment: Do you know that you can send an email to multiple recipients at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I use the  [Net::SMTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/index.html) library

Answer (score 0):

[RubyMail](http://www.rfc20.org/rubymail/) is an email handling library for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer to this, but this was just released:

http://adam.blog.heroku.com/past/2008/11/2/pony_the_express_way_to_send_email_from_ruby/

Might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

You might also consider taking a look at the [ActionMailer](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ActionMailer) component that ships as part of, but is not dependent on Rails.