# Bash script command line to mail a message in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, growl

I'm using the `atMonitor` app on my Mac mini

It allows one to send a message via `Growl` by using an included script.

The last two lines on the script are:

```
/usr/local/bin/growlnotify --appIcon atMonitor "atMonitor trigger" -m "$MESSAGE" &
exit 0
```

My questions:

1. I'd like to add one additional line to also send the `$MESSAGE` to me via e-mail.
2. How do I test the resultant script to ensure that it works ?

Thanks.

Howard

Comment: Does the app have a support forum? If so it would be better to ask  there.

Comment: I guess I could try incorprating Applescript in Bash:                   /usr/bin/osascript <<EOF                                                                                                                         [content of Applescript using Mail, which works when I test it in Terminal]                                                              end tell
EOF
exit 0                                                              .......                                                               and add it to the end of the Script.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question [Sending mail from a Bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822425/sending-mail-from-bash-shell-script)

I use a python script to page from my Mac. It requires a relay server.

https://github.com/jonzobrist/Bash-Admin-Scripts/blob/master/page.py
I put it in ${HOME}/bin and call with ${HOME}/bin/page.py "longer message in quotes"

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Author : jon@jonzobrist.com
#License : BSD/public/freeware

import smtplib
import sys

def prompt(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).strip()

fromaddr = "noreply@example.com"
#toaddrs = ['userA@example.com','userB@example.com','Phone1@txt.att.net','Phone2@txt.att.net','userC@example.com']
toaddrs = ['userA@example.com']
subject = "[ALERT] Alert from localhost"


msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"
         % (fromaddr,toaddrs,subject))
msg = msg + sys.argv[1]
server = smtplib.SMTP('server.ip.or.hostname')
#server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```