# Send email to myself using SMTP and Apache Camel

Tags: java, routes, smtp, apache-camel

I am trying to write an Apache Camel route for sending email to myself, based on Part 4 of this tutorial:

https://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident.html

```
from("file://target/subfolder")
.setHeader("subject", constant("new incident reported"))
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
// send the email
.to("smtp://myID@localhost?password=&to=myname@mycompany.com");
```

But I'm getting this, and no email in my inbox:

```
395  [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.
ReportIncidentRoutesTest  - Routing Rules are: 
[EventDrivenConsumerRoute[Endpoint[direct:start] -> 
Delegate(Delegate(Pipeline[DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(setHeader(org.apache.
camel.file.name, BeanExpression[bean:org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.
FilenameGenerator@244aeb52 method: generateFilename])), 
RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?level=error]], 
DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(sendTo(Endpoint[velocity:MailBody.vm])), 
RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?level=error]], 
DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(sendTo(Endpoint[file://target/subfolder])), 
RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?level=error]]]))], 
EventDrivenConsumerRoute[Endpoint[file://target/subfolder] -> 
Delegate(Delegate(Pipeline[DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(setHeader(To, 
myname@mycompany.com)), RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?
level=error]], DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(setHeader(subject, new incident 
reported)), RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?level=error]], 
DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(org.apache.camel.processor.
ConvertBodyProcessor@6e79839), 
RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?level=error]], 
DeadLetterChannel[Delegate(sendTo(Endpoint[smtp://myID@localhost?
password=&to=myname@mycompany.com])),
RecipientList[log:org.apache.camel.DeadLetterChannel?level=error]]]))]]
```

I'm not sure why, or how I can fix this problem.  I also seem to be getting these warnings when I run the test:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.2 is invalid, 
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, 
enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.7 is invalid, 
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, 
enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.7 is invalid, 
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, 
enable debug logging for more details

...

606  [main] WARN  org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter  - 
Overriding type converter from: StaticMethodTypeConverter: 
public static java.lang.String org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.
toString(javax.xml.transform.Source) throws javax.xml.transform.
TransformerException,java.io.IOException to: InstanceMethodTypeConverter: public 
java.lang.String org.apache.camel.converter.jaxp.XmlConverter.toString
(javax.xml.transform.Source) throws javax.xml.transform.TransformerException
```

Comment: What type of file are you consuming?

Comment: Are you using any custom type converters?

Comment: The warning message is harmless. You can need to check if there are any other warning or error message.

Comment: In answer to the questions: (1) The file type was a .vm.  (2) I don't think there are any custom type converters.  (3) I didn't see any other warning or error messages.

Comment: First, try to send a regular text file and not a Velocity template. Perhaps, Camel tries to do some magic.

Comment: Actually, the mail is being sent from a .txt file that was successfully autogenerated using a .vm.  The first part of the route (autogeneration of the .txt file) is working.

Answer (score 2):

The DEBUG and WARN messages can just be ignored.

Following route definition worked for me using Camel v2.12.3:

```
from("file://target/subfolder")
    .log("Working on file ${header.CamelFileName}")
    .setHeader("subject", simple("New incident: ${header.CamelFileName}"))
    .to("MY_ID@smtp://localhost?password=MY_PASSWORD&to=myname@mycompany.com");
```

After starting the route, you should see a message such as `Working on file XXX` in the log.

Perhaps not the Camel routing is the problem but the SMTP server on localhost. Try to send an email to your SMTP server using another email client and check if you receive any email. An example how to do this using a bash shell on MacOS can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822425/sending-mail-from-a-bash-shell-script).

Please, check if your SMTP server on localhost uses the default port. If not, add the port to the URI such as `localhost:MY_PORT`. For SMTP the default is `25`, for SMTPS this is `465`. The active port can be checked using telnet such as `telnet SERVERNAME 25`.

The SMTP server may not be the problem but the reading of the files. Check if the files in the `target/subfolder` are readable and not locked by Camel, i.e. check if there is no `fileName.camelLock` file.

Finally, verify that your route keeps running and doesn't stop before all your files are scanned, see http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html for more information about that.

To summarize my answer: Start small, split large routes into small ones and test them separately.

**EDIT:**
The most recent source code of tutorial-example-reportincident can be found here: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-reportincident.

Comment: doesn't recognize method log() and the smtp:// was the correct endpoint.  Camel version is 1.5.0

Comment: @La-comadreja The `log` EIP was introduced in Camel v2.2 (see https://camel.apache.org/logeip.html). I would highly recommend to upgrade to the latest version 2.12.3.

Comment: the problem is that I am going through a tutorial written in an older version.

Comment: @La-comadreja Use a more recent tutorial...?

Comment: It's Apache's.  I'm about to edit the question to show more info

Comment: @La-comadreja Try to update the Maven dependencies to the latest Camel version and check if it works.

Comment: doesn't work for 2.12, the names of what I'm using are older.

Comment: When I try to change to 2.12, error I'm getting is Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.camel:camel-example-reportincident:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.0

Comment: @La-comadreja Please use `2.12.3` and not  `2.12` or `2.12.0`

Comment: 2.12.3 gives this error: :camel-example-reportincident:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-mail:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-velocity:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.12.3: Could not find artifact org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.3 in central-local

Comment: @La-comadreja That's strange. Check if you have access to the Maven repository, see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.12.3

Comment: On my computer yes, but it also says  Could not find artifact org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.3 in central-local

Comment: Full error includes  ...Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.camel:camel-example-reportincident:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-mail:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-velocity:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.12.3, org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.12.3: Failure to find org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12.3 in http://MKTDEVPC3386:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted...

Comment: @La-comadreja Your local Maven may be broken. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of. Solve this issue by deleting the corresponding failed download artifact directory in your local repo.

Comment: same compiler error when I try to add "Always" to my settings file and -U to $mvn command.  Still at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51616/discussion-between-la-comadreja-and-peter)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51774/discussion-between-la-comadreja-and-peter)

Comment: @La-comadreja Could you finally solve your problem? You never accepted the answer...

Comment: Thank you for asking @Peter.  Actually, I couldn't email myself and moved on from this.